# How to run only the tests defined in feature files with nightwatch-cucumber

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

If in my `package.json` I define a yarn script `test` that only calls `nightwatch` command; It seems as it is that it'll run both the scenarios that are found in the `features` folder as well as any test that is not necessarily a test made with Cucumber (plain `nightwatch` tests under the `tests/` folder).

Is there a way for me to distinguish the execution of only the "`cucumber+nightwatch`" tests from the plain `nightwatch` ones, so I filter and only run from one of the two sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [author](https://github.com/mucsi96/) of `nightwatch-cucumber` suggested this approach via e-mail:

> use an environment variable in nightwatch configuration (JS based).
>   This environment variable can decide the source of the tests.
>
> One note: this package will be deprecated if nightwatch 1.x will come
>   out. So I suggest not to invest to much time with it instead use the
>   new nightwatch-api package.

A quick workaround to filter out plain `nightwatch` tests from the `cucumber+nightwatch` ones was to edit the `src_folders` in the `nightwatch.json` file to an empty array, like this:

```
{
  "src_folders" : [],
  ...
}
```